# Exception at ENSURE(strDocName.LoadString(AFX_IDS_UNTITLED))

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am getting an exception in this function

```
{
    CString strDocName;
    if (!GetDocString(strDocName, CDocTemplate::docName) ||
        strDocName.IsEmpty())
    {
        // use generic 'untitled'
        ENSURE(strDocName.LoadString(AFX_IDS_UNTITLED));
    }
    pDocument->SetTitle(strDocName);
}
```

`AFX_IDS_UNTITLED` is defined in the string table but under Spanish resources but that doesn't help.
I haven't ever worked with localized resources and I have no idea what is happening. I have been stuck in this for 3 days. It would be nice if someone can help out.

Note: I have been porting 2005 VS code to 2017 VS.

Comment: What is the exception? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: *"I have no idea what is happening"* - A debugger will tell you. MFC comes with source code so that you can single-step into library code.

Comment: @IInspectable LoadString is defined as LoadStringA. I actually can't step into the definition of the function.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it just says sequenceEditor has triggered a breakpoint. 
Doesn't tell if it's a seg fault or smth

Comment: `LoadString` is clearly a class member. That class will ultimately forward the call to the Windows API. Before that you'll get to inspect the arguments. That's entirely helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable the argument sent is AFX_IDS_UNTITLED but LoadStringA takes more arguments, idk if they are declared = 0 in the declaration.

Comment: LoadStringA(
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_ UINT uID,
    _Out_writes_to_(cchBufferMax, return + 1) LPSTR lpBuffer,
    _In_ int cchBufferMax
    );

Comment: @IInspectable also, this function where the program breaks is in docsingl.cpp which is a part of mfc. I think I alter the code at this level

Comment: @IInspectable oh I see. When I press F12 on LoadString, it takes me to LoadString A which doesn't look like a member function. 
I looked for LoadString in CString class and i could find a different definition of the it which it should be linked to

Comment: There are lots of discssions about this. For example:https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?167746-Error-reading-standard-string-resources Have you included the AFX resources referred to in that discussion because they imply the issue. And you said about resources only in Spanish. So if you are using English .... then it does not find the string. Make sure you got the correct resources (MFC DLL) available for the executable ...

Comment: Just google this. Several things about it. Here is another: http://code.fitness/post/2015/12/win32-afx-ids-untitled.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that you are using the `ENSURE` macro in your code. If you check the definition of that macro it is:

`#define ENSURE(cond) ENSURE_THROW(cond, ::AfxThrowInvalidArgException() )`

`LodString returns` FALSE` if it is unable to load the specified string (in your case [MFC Predefined Symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/mfc-predefined-symbols?view=msvc-160) it mentions the aforementioned ID.

You said:

> `AFX_IDS_UNTITLED` is defined in the string table but under **Spanish** resources but that doesn't help.

I assume that this issue is happening when you are using English? If which case you simply need to go to the English STRINGTABLE and add a new entry. In the properties type in `AFX_IDS_UNTITLED` and provide a phrase you want to use.

---

You will find that this ID is defined in the file `afxres.h`:

```
// General strings
#define AFX_IDS_OPENFILE                0xF000
#define AFX_IDS_SAVEFILE                0xF001
#define AFX_IDS_ALLFILTER               0xF002
#define AFX_IDS_UNTITLED                0xF003
#define AFX_IDS_SAVEFILECOPY            0xF004
#define AFX_IDS_PREVIEW_CLOSE           0xF005
#define AFX_IDS_UNNAMED_FILE            0xF006
#define AFX_IDS_HIDE                    0xF011
```

So you need to ensure that this header is included in your resources. How do you do this?

- Right-click your resources file in the **Resource View** tab.
- Select **Resource Includes**.
- Make sure that the file is included.

[image]

Comment: Hi,
i actually figured it out before. I looked at the answer today. The issue was I had to include #define AFX_IDS_UNTITLED                0xF003 in the string table of the language I was using. Once that is done, it progresses without an issue